# I'm working with JS, I know the use of replace method,Can you explain this specific code => /.(?=.{4})/g in the below function?

Tags: javascript, masking

```
function maskify(cc) {
  return cc.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, "#");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is regex here `/.(?=.{4})/`

> Any character followed by any character four times.

[image]

```js
function maskify(cc) {
  return cc.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, "#");
}

console.log(maskify("Awesome"));
```

If `any character` is followed by `four characters except newline` then it will replace it with `#`

`a` is followed by `weso`, replace `a` with `#`

`w` is followed by `esom`, replace `w` with `#`

`e` is followed by `some`, replace `e` with `#`

After `e` there is no character which is follwed by `4 characters`, so it won't replace it with `#`

Comment: Could you share a link to the tool you used to create this image?

Comment: sure [regulex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24)